# Microsoft Android Emulator Shows Blank Form When Debugging

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

I am trying to run a Xamarin form called 'FormsApp' on my andriod emulator in visual studio. The Emulator boots up fine and renders. However, after clicking "start debugging" the form deploys to the emulator but only shows a blank white from.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga4lR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOBcq.png

I have tried playing around with my OpenGL ES Renderer settings and OpenGL ES API level settings as well. Switching to swiftshader/ANGLE D3D9/ and Compatibility (OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0) did not work. It's Still a blank white Screen when debugging.

```
namespace FormsApp
{
    class ContentPageExample : ContentPage
    {
        public ContentPageExample()
        {

            Label labelLarge = new Label
            {
                Text = "Label",
                FontSize = 40,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            Label labelSmall = new Label
            {
                Text = "This control is great for\n" +
                        "displaying one or more\n" +
                        "lines of text.",
                FontSize = 20,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
            };

            Button button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Make It So",
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
            };

            button.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                button.Text = "It is so!";
            };

            Entry entry = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Username",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Keyboard = Keyboard.Text
            };

            BoxView boxView = new BoxView
            {
                Color = Color.Silver,
                WidthRequest = 150,
                HeightRequest = 150,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
            };

            Image image = new Image
            {
                Source = "monkey.png",
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
            };

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                image.Opacity = .5;
                await Task.Delay(200);
                image.Opacity = 1;
            };
            image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    labelLarge,
                    labelSmall,
                    button,
                    entry,
                    boxView,
                    image
                },
                HeightRequest = 1500
            };

            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView
            {
                //BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Content = stackLayout
            };

            //this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black; //White

            // Accomodate iPhone status bar.
            this.Padding = new Thickness(10, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 10, 5);

            this.Content = scrollView;

        }

    }
}
```

No error messages..

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the  `ContentPageExample` as `MainPage`? I just test the `ContentPageExample` and it works well.

For example in class `App`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new ContentPageExample();
    }
}
```